# Replace NaN with 'the best value possible' while using Pandas dateframe with ta-lib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Many indicators (ATR, RSI, EMA ...) will provide NaN as a result for the first N bars where N stands for the 'length' the indicator uses.

Only after N periods the indicator will return a calculated value, i.e. `df.ta.atr(10)`

With

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

those NaN-values can be set to 0 (or any other value) in order to avoid problems while comparing values.
I would prefer to replace the value 0 with 'the best possible value'.

Suppose we want to use ATR(10).
In such case I prefer to calculate ATR(9), ATR(8), ...., ATR(2) for the first rows that currently have NaN as a result and supply a 'reasonable' value for row(0).

While calculating HeikenAshi values this is pricipally what is done as for the first row a different formula is used compared to other rows as the formula relies on a previous value for row zero as well.
So I wonder why such an approach is not used more often.

How can I achieve that an indicator will not produce NaN anymore if the number of rows is less than the 'length' of the indicator and provide 'the best possible value' based on the same calculations but with a shorter length?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there small input and expected output?